# How to Zip Files using PowerShell (without PS Version 5 or .NET Framework 4.5)

Tags: powershell, scripting, zip

I'm looking for a way to create a new ZIP Archive or add files to an existing archive using Powershell. This script is going to be ran on very old systems some of which are still using Powershell Version 2 and .NET Framework 3.0 or earlier. There isn't any possibility of upgrading because they are client production systems that aren't connected to the internet and I don't have the ability to install any add-ons or extensions.

Due to how old these systems are I can't use `Compress-Archive` or `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. I have the whole script complete apart from the actual zipping function. All the other solutions online have told me to either use the .NET 4.5 way or the powershell V5 way and that isn't possible on the systems that I'm working on. Any ideas?

Here is a link to my code: https://pastebin.com/m8FjFhcr
Line #113 is where the zip commands would go.

Comment: Would you be able to copy 7zip.exe to those machines and do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is going to run as a scheduled task and I wouldn't be able to leave 7zip on the servers.

Comment: How about using VBScript? `Shell.Application` can zip files [by copying](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php) into compressed a destination. This is quite a hack, but given the constraints, worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Shell.Application`.

```bsh
# Create an empty zip file
$byte = @([byte]80,75,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes(".\Desktop\zip.zip", $byte)

# New Shell.Application ComObject
$sa = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# Path to folder containing items you wish to zip
$in = $sa.NameSpace("C:\Users\Ash\Desktop\test") # Specify full path

# Path to zip file created earlier
$out = $sa.NameSpace("C:\Users\Ash\Desktop\zip.zip") # Specify full path

# Copy files in to archive.
$out.CopyHere($in.Items(), 4) # 4 = No Progress Box
```

[Folder.CopyHere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere)

Everyone likes a reusable function and being able to use relative paths...

```bsh
function ConvertTo-Archive {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string]$Path,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Output
    )
    # Convert relative path if one has been used.
    $Source = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path)
    $Destination = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Output)

    $byte = @([byte]80,75,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($Destination, $byte)
    $sa = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $in = $sa.NameSpace($Source)
    $out = $sa.NameSpace($Destination)
    $out.CopyHere($in.Items(), 4)
}
```

Usage

```bsh
ConvertTo-Archive -Path .\Desktop\test\ -Output .\Desktop\zip.zip
```

Or

```bsh
Get-Item .\Desktop\test\ | ConvertTo-Archive -Output .\Desktop\zip.zip
```